# define many entities and search at single entity type at solr

Tags: php, mysql, solr, indexing, full-text-search

I have database with 4 tables which is person,location,cities,countries now i want to be able to search in every particular table (like search for all countries start with united) and also search in all of them once (like search for all person who have locations in city start with 'c' in country 'united state').

I have tried to define entity for every table and nested entity for the last case, but i don't have an idea how to just write the query to do the up searches to tell solr that i want to search in persons only or in all tables.

Please i need code example to solve this.

I'm using php/mysql.

Answer (score 4):

If you have defined an Entity for each table as well as a Combined one, you can add an identifier to each of the entity and use that identifier to filter the results.
e.g.
Add a field type to each entity with fixed values as PERSON, LOCATION CITY ....
And for queries use `fq=type:PERSON` to filter the results for the specific entity.